# How to get user input in a Windows Form from a function in a library?

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

I have a library of classes that perform various tasks.  I would like some of those tasks to occur in response to user input from a Windows Form.  What I've tried so far is to set up an input interface in the library, like this:

```
public interface IInputter
{
    string sendInput();
}
```

Implement the interface in the form:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form,IInputter
    {
        string sentText=null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string sendInput()
        {
            string inputText=sentText;
            sentText=null;
            return inputText;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls*)|*.xls*";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                sentText = ofd.FileName; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Pass the form as a parameter when calling the library's function from the form code:

```
public partial class StartForm : Form
{
    public StartForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show();
        Main main = new Main();
        main.main(f1);
    }
}
```

And then call the input function from the library function:

```
    public string main(IInputter inputter)
    { 
     do
     {
        testBk = inputter.sendInput();
     }
     while (testBk == null);
     return testBk;
    }
```

However, `Form1` is not fully loading; there are just empty spaces where the controls should be, so the `While` loop just runs infinitely without having any way for the form to send input to the library function via the `IInputter.sendInput()` function.

I'm sure there must be a more 'built-in' way to set up a data stream that can be accessed from within a library whose interfaces are implemented in the form; what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Your form is interactive, so your interface would make more sense exposing an *event*:

```
public interface IInputter
{
    event EventHandler<InputReceivedEventArgs> ReceivedInput;
}

public class InputReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public InputReceivedEventArgs(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form, IInputter
{
    public event EventHandler<InputReceivedEventArgs> ReceivedInput = delegate { };


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Excel files (*.xls*)|*.xls*" };
        var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ReceivedInput(this, new InputReceivedEventArgs(ofd.FileName));
            sentText = ofd.FileName; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to consume:

```
public string main(IInputter inputter)
{
    string receivedInput = null;

    inputter.ReceivedInput += (s, e) => YourLibrary.DoSomething(e.Text);
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Why use `string receivedInput=null` (it looks superfluous)?  2. I'm trying to test this with `string x; inputter.ReceivedInput += (s, e) => x = e.Text; x += "hello";` but that gives the error `Use of unassigned local variable 'x'`.  3. In `Form1`, the `EventHandler<InputReceivedEventArgs> ReceivedInput` declaration gives the error `The type or namespace name 'InputReceivedEventArgs' could not be found` even though I've added a reference to the library.